# Using external (RAID) HDD for new operation system

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, usb, raid

I have a question about using a RAID HDD setup on a laptop. My laptop is very nice (intel i7 Haswell, 20 GB 1600 MHz, 3 GB dedicated GPU) but my HDD are slow (2x1TB 5400 RPM) and even worse - they have windows on them! I like keeping windows on it for gaming, etc. but I would also like to run Linux on this computer.

Before anyone recommends this - I tried running on one of the disks but accidently wiped out my boot partition - as there was no windows disk included, I had to send it back and get a new laptop. Suffice it to say that I don't want to try that again - so in the mean time I have been running a VM which has actually been working pretty well, but again, on a slow HDD.

Here is what I would like to do and please tell me if this is possible ...

I would like to build an external HDD system with more than one HDD and RAID0 it so I can get very fast speeds. I have a USB 3.0 ports, so if I am correct, the USB connection to my laptop should not be a bottleneck. If that is true, is it possible to build a RAID system on external hard drives, install Linux on it, then use that for my linux workstation instead of my VM?

TL;DR - here are the questions:
(1) How would I go about building, for example, a 3x1TB external RAID0 that I could connect and disconnect from a USB 3.0 port at will?
(2) Supposing this setup worked, will the USB 3.0 connection be a bottleneck?
(3) How would I go about installing (and then booting from) a totally new operating system on this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a full answer, but I think it's worth it.

"...there was no windows disk included..." - Burn your "Recovery" disks from the computer. They don't generally send Windows disks anymore.

I'd recommend going with a single smaller (or two smaller) SATA SSD drives instead - The speed on that will be better than USB. If you use a mirrored RAID1(Mirrored), you'll lose ~10-15% (if I remember right) of the speed of the drives. If you use RAID0, your performance will be a bit better.

[USB 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)'s speed maxes out at around 5 Gb/s. SATA is 6 Gb/s. In either format, your bottle neck will either be the drives or the drive controller (RAID controller in your case). You'll have less of a controller bottleneck if you go with a RAID0.

If you do want to go with some type of remote RAID, I'd highly recommend a NAS device that has RAID instead. But what about the speed? 1 Gb/s not enough? Chances are that your computer won't use that much regularly anyways. Unless you are running an OS off of this (and I wouldn't - Dual boot instead or use a VHD), you won't notice the slowdown much, as long as you have gigabit Ethernet or higher running on your network.

1. You buy one. Don't build one.
2. Yes, 3.0 has a max speed of 5 Gb/s over the entire bus, although your chipset may be a problem too (USB to chipset can be a slower connection than 5 Gb/s).
3. Burn the OS disks (Recovery disks). You can install GRUB/Linux as the boot device, which will then boot into either Linux or run the Windows bootloader. If you format your drives and install Linux first, Windows doesn't always play nicely with other boot systems (like GRUB).

If you want to not touch the host OS, take a look at installing on a VHD instead - You only add a boot option to Windows, create a VHD, then boot into the VHD file through the Windows bootloader. The VHD is just a file on your computer, not a new partition.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using a VHD. I am working with large (100's of GB) files and having to do a lot of datamining on them which is why I am looking for faster speeds. Right now a SSD just seems too expensive for the amount of space I need, which is why I was looking into RAID HDD for data storage.

Comment: sorry, maybe I lied. I am using a VM and the file is a .vdi file - is this different than a VHD? Can I boot directly into a .vdi file?

Comment: A VHD is Microsoft's version of a VDI file (VMWare, right?). Apparently there is no noteworthy performance decreases by booting to a VHD that is present on your normal OS's drive (`c:\linux.vhd` in your Windows drive), but you get to avoid repartitioning the existing OS and screwing with the boot sequence (well, you still have to add the boot option, but it's not adding another boot loader in front of Windows). See [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/virtualization/77618-linux-vhd-boot-made-possible.html) for information on booting from a VHD.